# How to drag and drop a text file for modification

Tags: jquery

Basically I'm writing a pure client side jQuery application. For the first step I need to get input from a text file (html file to be specific).
First I want to drag and drop a file into an html element, better if it can be displayed in the element (like a div or a textarea). Then I'll have to store the content in a variable because the application is used to modify the text.
Basic jQuery can't do this. I found several jQuery plugin which can do drag and drop uploade, but didn't find one that support file modifying.
Does anyone know how to do this? I don't need file upload function since this is pure client-side.

Comment: You need server-side code to do this after the file is uploaded -- store the file, then display it to the client and let them edit it. JavaScript (thankfully) can't modify files on the client machine like that.

Comment: @Blazemonger I understand the security issue, but I've heard there are similar implementation in HTML5. Might be wrong though...After all, all I want is to save the copy/paste trouble for users.

Comment: As I said: you need server-side code to upload a copy of the file, and then present that server-side copy to the user for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Blazemonger said, I cannot achieve my goal on client side. So what I did is to move all file processing to server side. On client side, I use jQuery file upload plugin for file uploading.